# How can I add Chrome's Incognito Window mode to Unity's Dash?

Tags: google-chrome, unity-dash

Is it possible to add Chrome's Incognito Mode to Unity Dash? By clicking on the Chrome Incognito Mode icon, I envision to open Chrome in a new incognito mode window. I still want to keep the default Google Chrome launcher icon and don't want to make the incognito mode the default mode.

[image]

Comment: Please see my edits. I don't want to make incognito mode the default mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Unity Dash ? No, not possible. It only displays applications,not their quicklists/options. However, if you pin an application to the launcher, you can open incognito from Chrome's quicklist:

[image]

Comment: Not possible ? When you install Bleachbit for example, you have two launchers in the Dash : Bleachbit and Bleachbit (as root). I don't know how it was designed, but it seems to be possible, or am I wrong @Serg ? :)

Comment: @cl-netbox it has two `.desktop` files in  `/usr/share/applications` folder, `/usr/share/applications/bleachbit.desktop` and `/usr/share/applications/bleachbit-root.desktop` . What I'm saying is that Chrome has only one , single `.desktop` file, and that's the only thing that shows up in Dash. One can create icon for incognito mode, but as Jacob mentioned, it could potentially lead to unexpected behavior. You cannot view sub-menus/options of that .desktop file in Dash either

Answer (score 3):

### How to create a .desktop

- Create an empty file
- Write the following:

  > ```
  > [Desktop Entry]
  > Name=Chrome Incognito
  > Comment=Opens chrome in incognito mode
  > Exec=google-chrome --incognito
  > Icon=google-chrome
  > Terminal=false
  > Type=Application
  > StartupNotify=true
  > Categories=GNOME;
  > OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
  > X-GNOME-Keywords=Network;Chrome;Incognito
  > ```

  *Name, Comment, Icon, and X-GNOME-Keywords* may be changed as your prefer.

**Icon**: All icons that are under the directory `/usr/share/pixmaps` don't need to have their full path specified, but their filename without the extension. For example, if the icon file is `/usr/share/pixmaps/wallch.png`, then the Icon field should be just 'wallch'. All other icons should have their full path specified.

- Save it and name it as `SOMETHING.desktop`
- Now you should be able to find it, using the keywords used at *X-GNOME-
  Keywords*

You can easily add it to the launcher as well, just by dragging the .desktop to the launcher, it will be automatically locked there.

---

Source / Extra information: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Comment: Better not create multiple .desktop files, calling the same application in their first Exec= line. It creates unexpected behaviour in the launcher, grouping windows under the wrong icon.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Would it be better to Exec=/path/to/script , script being just `google-chrome --incognito` ?